# Python3 : Print a dictionnary values to 'a ': [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 9] into 'a ': 1-3, 5-6, 9?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm a begginner in Python,

I created a dictionary, with as keys the words of a text, and the values representing the lines where the words are.

the text :

```
text = 'You needed me\nOoh, you needed me\nFeel a little more and give a little less\nKnow you hate to confess\nBut, baby, who, you needed me'
```

the code :

```
index = {}
line = text.split('\n')
for i, line in enumerate(line, 1):
    for word in line.split(' '):
           if word not in index:
                   index[word] = []
           index[word].append(i)
```

output :

```
index 

{'You': [1], 'needed': [1, 2, 5], 'me': [1, 2, 5], 'Ooh,': [2], 'you': [2, 4, 5], 'Feel': [3], 'a': [3, 3], 'little': [3, 3], 'more': [3], 'and': [3], 'give': [3], 'less': [3], 'Know': [4], 'hate': [4], 'to': [4], 'confess': [4], 'But,': [5], 'baby,': [5], 'who,': [5]}
```

Now, I would like to order the consecutive numbers of values like these :

`'a ': [1, 2, 3]` to `'a ': 1-3`

or

`'a ': [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 9]` to `'a ': 1-3, 5-6, 9`

Comment: Did you arrive at a solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

The [`intspan`](https://pypi.org/project/intspan/) module would likely be suitable to your needs:

```
>>> import intspan
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 9]
>>> str(intspan.intspan(a))
'1-3,5-6,9'
>>> intspan.intspan(a).ranges()
[(1, 3), (5, 6), (9, 9)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) from the standard library:

```
from itertools import groupby, count

def contiguous(a):
    c = count() 
    out = []
    for key, group in  groupby(a, key=lambda x: x-next(c)):
        group = list(group)
        g = str(group[0])
        if len(group) > 1:
            g += '-' + str(group[-1])
        out.append(g)
    return ', '.join(out)

print(contiguous([1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 9]))
# 1-3, 5-6, 9
```

The idea is that in contiguous groups, the difference between the values and the indices (which we get using the `count` iterator) is constant, allowing `groupby` to group them together.